# i want to get location attribute from response header in jQuery how it possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I have jsp page while clear the session value from cookies. I want to reload page and redirected to `login.jsp` page. using jQuery or javascript.

How can I get location attribute from response header in javascript or jQuery?

> Content-Length    0 Date  Thu, 10 Jul 2014 06:42:40 GMT
>
> **Location    **localhost:8080/Baldknobbers-Live/login.htm****
>
> Server    Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> Set-Cookie    JSESSIONID=8BF0090EFA8D05B09EA5E6F170DEE52F;
>
> Path=/Baldknobbers-Live/; HttpOnly view source Accept text/html, */*;
>
> q=0.01 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Cache-Control no-cache Connection keep-alive Content-Length   0
>   Cookie    JSESSIONID=; DWRSESSIONID= Host 192.168.1.201:8080
>   Pragma    no-cache
>   Referer   localhost:8080/Baldknobbers-Live/admin/home.htm
>   User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/30.0 X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: i want to get value of location attribute which bind in response header see my post.

Comment: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) my ajax function is not called when session is not available (clear) want to check if session is not available than redirect to login.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can get location url of the page using window.location and can redirect or reload the page .

```
window.location = "http://www.page-2.com";
```